# Adding a column to "Cases" summary/main page grid

Tags: view, customization, dynamics-crm-4

I need to add a column to the "Cases" Activity and History view

[image: http://bit.ly/jCKmXk]

I want to add the a column for the `Description` field of a case record.

Extra: I'd like to limit the amount of text shown in the cell but maybe have the full description appear in the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto `Settings -> Customizations -> Customize Entities`. Select `Incident` and open the Views. Select the view which you want to edit. On the right side of the editor you can add new columns.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Altought I was looking for the "Case" Entity.

Comment: Sorry, I had the schema name in mind. You are right, the display name is case